# During Linq-to-SQL insert, when does an auto-increment primary key value become available?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Does the automatically generated value of the primary key column become accessible after `InsertOnSubmit`, after `SubmitChanges`, or at some other time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is available after `SubmitChanges` call.

Just did a simple test.

```
DBDataContext db = new DBDataContext();
TestTable tb = new TestTable();
tb.Name = "Some Name";
db.TestTables.InsertOnSubmit(tb);

Console.WriteLine(tb.ID); //returned 0

db.SubmitChanges();
Console.WriteLine(tb.ID); //returned 1
```

Before `SubmitChanges` 0 was returned as ID, and after `SubmitChanges` the incremented ID is returned.

Comment: This was not the case with my code. If the OP is having this issue, maybe he's in the same boat I was. I don't know what caused it, but do you think I would leave such a short, clear answer, if I wasn't sure?

Comment: @Jasmine, I am not sure how your comment is related to my answer, but as far as downvote is concerned, Your statement is not right. One does not have to Refresh the object to get the ID, after SubmitChanges. If you had that issue previously then there could be other things involved.

Comment: It's related to your answer because your code didn't work. I hate this site.

Comment: @Jasmine, My code didn't work ?? and the OP accepted it ?? Create a new console app with new dbml file and try the code above, That is exactly what I did to find the answer. It works.

Comment: Well, in my case I was working with real world stuff, not test apps. Identity column was not available until Refresh. Not gonna argue it. That's what happened. And yes, I'm aware that is contrary to the docs.